# SQL Translation

Tags: sql, sql-server, translation

I have a database where I wish to have the option or support for translating varchars (for example, `CustomerInfo`, `Country`, Name of City) into different languages, how do I go about it the best way? :)

Comment: Do you mean different values depending on the language? Add a language column to your tables, so you store English values in one row, and French values in another row. (Same "id", but different language_id.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You mean Creating a language table, with a couple of languages  and link them with foreign keys? (Junction table probably needed i guess)

Comment: Do you have table with data in the language that you want to support?

Comment: In the language i want to support?  I have a table with data yes, but nothing in the table for supporting translation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of Language Translation in SQL Server using Microsoft Translator APIs & SQL CLR

see if below link helps

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2013/05/04/language-translation-in-sql-server-using-bing-translator-apis-amp-sql-clr.aspx

Comment: Thanks, will check it out in a few minutes :)

Comment: It was a cool api, but dont like the idea of downloading. thanks anyway!